# AutoCompleteTextView that limits options to just those in the adapter set for it and doesn't require two characters before the list is visible

Tags: android, android-layout, autocompletetextview

I want to use the `AutoCompleteTextView` to provide a list of options so when the user clicks on it they get the full list but then as they type it reduces the number of items as they search for specific items. And secondly it needs to limit the entry to just the options available in the adapter provided.

Why doesn't `AutoCompleteTextView` do this already? Because you have to type two characters in before the list even appears, I would like this list to be scrollable the moment the `TextView` has focus.

**xml code :**

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text" />
```

This is what I currently have an it's susceptible to the problem I described above.

**java code :**

```
    List<String> typeList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
        typeList.add(i, items.get(i).getName());
    }
    String[] descriptions = typeList.toArray(new String[0]);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> autoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
    final AutoCompleteTextView categoryInput = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteCategory);
```

Alright! Managed to figure out a solution, quite simple in the end, add a `OnFocusChangeListener()` to the `AutoCompleteTextView` and then if the view has focus do `showDropDown()`

This way anyone who clicks it immediately gets the full list and as they type the list shrinks in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override `enoughToFilter()` method in `AutoCompleteTextView` to achieve filtering happen without user entering minimum 1 or 2 characters.

Basically create your own custom view by extending `AutoCompleteTextView` and override `enoughtToFilter()` method to return `true` always.

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enoughToFilter() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it would have worked as well, I just edited my post with how I got it to work using a OnFocusChangedListener.

Comment: @CarlingKnight awesome.. The downside of OnFocusChangedListener is that once AutoCompleteTextView is in focus and when you touch the view multiple times the dropdown will be visible only for the first time. Instead you can use setOnTouchListener. You can reproduce this by touching on the view, dismiss the dropdown by entering some character and clearing it or pressing back button.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, you're right, onClickListener works better, thanks!

Comment: @CarlingKnight Since you are using onClickListener, I would like to know if the dropdown is visible on first click itself or is it working only after tapping twice?

Comment: I implemented two listeners in the end, with the OnClickListener it only happens on the second click. However if I put a OnFocusChangeListener as well which both do showDropDown then it works on first click and all future clicks!

Comment: I just realized that you said onTouchListener in your comment not onClickListener... I apologise.

Comment: @CarlingKnight alright, I faced the same issue and onTouchListener solved it. This is because the view takes the first click (tap) event to focus where onFocusChanged gets called first and then the next click event goes to onClickListener.. Happy coding..

Answer (score 4):

> **As you written this :** Because you have to type two characters in
>   before the list even appears

If I am not understanding wrong you are looking for how to set List after typing two or more character.

you can either set it via xml `android:completionThreshold="2"`
or you can set via programatically,

Use [setThreshold()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setThreshold%28int%29).

> *public void **setThreshold** (int*
>   threshold)
>   Since: API Level 1
>   Specifies the minimum number of
>   characters the user has to type in the
>   edit box before the drop down list is
>   shown.
>   When threshold is less than or equals 0, a threshold of 1 is applied.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I need, however that still requires a single character to be entered as entering 0 just applies a threshold of one character.

Comment: try to change the `thresold` value.

Comment: Wow messed up with adding comments three times, I was trying to say I get this when setting the threshold to 0:
Error:(23, 38) Integer value out of range (at 'completionThreshold' with value '0').

Comment: @CarlingKnight why you are set `0` value.

Comment: So that when the user taps the text view, even without typing anything they get a list of items. Entering 1 requires the user to still type 1 character before getting the suggestions.

Comment: @CarlingKnight see my update answer. you can not set `less than or equal to 0`. read the documentation.

Comment: I did read the documentation...  In my first comment I mentioned how entering zero just applies a default of one character?

Comment: @CarlingKnight as per document you have to minimum set `1`.so change your code and see.

Comment: Okay so AutoCompleteTextView can't do what I'm after then, if the minimum is 1 and I need it to create the dropdown when the user taps with nothing in the textview I need to look elsewhere?

Comment: @CarlingKnight yes you are right and if my answer is helpful then you can mark as accept answer so it will help other.

Comment: to show the list of items when the user taps, you can do the following (kotlin): `autoCompleteTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus -> if (hasFocus) { autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown() } }`
but the list will still disappear when deleting all characters.